# Name for hyperbolic analogue of a parallelogram?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Is there a name for a hyperbolic quadrilateral where opposite sides have equal length, or equivalently so that the diagonals bisect each other, as shown below?

[image: Hyperbolic quadrilateral with opposite sides equal length]

"Hyperbolic parallelogram" is the obvious name (and it seems to be used a little), but has the obvious downside that these quadrilaterals generalize many properties of Euclidean parallelograms, but not the property that gives the "parallelogram" its name.

In a paper I need the easy lemma that
$$
\cosh (OX)\cosh(OY) = \frac{\cosh(XY) + \cosh(YZ)}{2}
$$
generalizing the Euclidean parallelogram law. In general these quadrilaterals seem pretty pleasant to work with.

Comment: This article can help: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10958-022-05935-4

Comment: @user376343 Thanks! That reference goes through the things you get by generalizing several properties of a Euclidean parallelogram, but doesn't really propose terminology (other than the generic "quasiparallelogram", specifically of type II). But that's a lousy name for what is clearly the best generalization (the only one with more than one characterization on the list of 10).

Comment: Hyperbolic rhombus avoids the parallel part and captures the opposite sides being the same length.

Comment: Unfortunately "rhombus" requires all sides have equal length (and so the diagonals crossing at right angles), which I do not want in my application. Otherwise it would be a great term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a self-describing term, consider **point-symmetric quadrilateral**. Alternatively, **rhomboid** is an uncommon term for parallelograms, but traditionally only refers to parallelograms that are neither rectangles or rhombi.

Comment: Thanks, these are both great.

Comment: Nice. The [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhomboid) even gives the reference to Euclid Definition 22 where one finds the word $\rho\omicron\mu\beta\omicron\epsilon\iota\delta\epsilon\sigma$ with this exact definition.